# Put values in JTable, using setModel();

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I created JTable, using Design View - Table.
But, I want the values to come from SQL query, not to be inserted manulally.
So I select on table: model -> Custom Code, then there is: `jTable1.setModel();`

What I can put there? I tried with methods to return value, but NetBeans tell me, `String cannot to be converted to TableModel`.

I can't modify the code `initComponents()`, which is generated from NetBeans, I can only put method there.

So how to get values from SQL or what I can use here `setModel()` to retrieve the result from SQL.

Table: 3 columns x 7 lines

The code:

```
  private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(resultsTable());
        jTable1.setToolTipText("");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
 ... more code for the frame .....
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: *"I can't modify the code `initComponents()`, which is generated from NetBeans.."*  If you can't sort out how to make your IDE do as *you* require, then you're not using it, so much as it is using you.  I recommend (for the moment) dumping the IDE and figure this out in Java code.

Comment: See [this tutorial](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/)

Comment: @Robin: Thank you! This works perfect for me. Good example and understandable for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also make your table model by extending AbstractTableModel class and overriding appropriate methods.

Take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Answer (score 0):

I found very easy solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbYxThOFsLI

This is exactly what I want, using Table, generated from NetBeans.

Thanks to everyone!